# Validate alfanumric with dot

Tags: c#, java, regex

I need to validate if string is type alfanumric with dot

I try with @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" which is not working

the string can be like

abc.abc

abc

abc.abc

not other special char like ^ or & ( etc
what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle any number of dots in your input, then push the dot inside the character class.

```
^[.a-zA-Z0-9]+$
  ^ here
```

If you want to match only one or zero dot(i mean optional) at the middle, then:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Or,

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: Thanks but its not working for e.g. abc.ffdf.dfdd.fdc

Comment: @JohnJerrby did you see the last regex? just change `?` into `*`.